# Is there any limitation in our ability to come up with a theory or hypothesis to understand brain?

Tags: experimental-psychology, consciousness, unconscious

We are observing the behaviors (either through behavioral experiments or observing brain activation through neuroscience experiments) based on the GIVEN TASK to the participants and trying to understand the observed behavior characteristics.

I wonder 
(i) if there is any limitation in our ability to speculate through hypothesis and theory to understand whats happening in the brain,
(ii) if there is any limitation in manipulate the third person to test the hypothesis
(iii) Is there a pattern in our 'ability' to coming up with a hypothesis or theory in understand the brain. Like we tend to make analogies, extrapolations etc.

Comment: try explaining what you are asking better, because this question is very hard to understand.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it is better now.